# data type mismatch in SQL Spark

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to extract a small part of an array and have casted the array into string type, then use split/split_part to extract the data. But jupyter keeps saying that the column, which I have already casted it from array to string, cannot be resolved due to data type mismatch.

here's my sql code:
TRIM(SPLIT(CAST(SPLIT(CAST(log as STRING),' ',4) as STRING),'OpenLevel39',2)) as server_launch_date

or another line of code is also using the same method:
datediff('day', DATE(TRIM(SPLIT(SPLIT(CAST(log as STRING),' ',4),'OpenLevel39',2))), current_date) as server_create_in_days

and here's what the error says:
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'trim(split(CAST(split(CAST(spark_catalog.jxm.timeframe.`log` AS STRING), ' ', 4) AS STRING), 'OpenLevel39', 2))' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, 'split(CAST(split(CAST(spark_catalog.jxm.timeframe.`log` AS STRING), ' ', 4) AS STRING), 'OpenLevel39', 2)' is of array type.; line 20 pos 0;

please can anyone help me with this problem? much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Spark's `split` returns an array with a length of at most `limit` as stated in the documentation.

On the other hand, `trim` requires the first parameter to be of type `string`; you are passing an `array`.

You can try to `cast` the array to `string` first, then use `trim`, as below:

```
trim(CAST(split(CAST(split(CAST(spark_catalog.jxm.timeframe.log AS STRING), ' ', 4) AS STRING), 'OpenLevel39', 2) as STRING))
```

However, this kind of does not make sense because an `array` has no spaces before or after (even after casted to string).

Good luck!